# ImportError: cannot import name 'URL' from 'sqlalchemy.engine' while initiating rasa

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, rasa, rasa-nlu

When I run `rasa init` in the anaconda prompt, I am getting into this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'URL' from 'sqlalchemy.engine'
> (c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py)

Answer (score 3):

The name `URL` is only exposed in `sqlalchemy.engine` from version 1.4.  You need to ensure that your SQLAlchemy installation is up to date:

```bash
python -m pip install --upgrade sqlalchemy
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to the "c:\users\user\anaconda3" and check for lib folder. If you find Lib instead of lib, then change the folder name to lib.